# AKS Cluster Created has no External IP Address

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-cluster) to create a new AKS cluster.  This has worked fine, however, when I look at the cluster I have noticed there is no External-IP (it shows )

How do I add an external IP address so that I can access the cluster externally?

I am using AKS within Azure

Paul

Comment: What do you want to expose?

Comment: I have a simple web api Docker image that works fine locally now I want to host it in aks and call it in post man

Comment: Deploy a Load Balancer service to front your deployment (pod)

Comment: Ah ok will see if I can find tutorial for that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/intro-to-kubernetes-on-azure/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

kubectl apply -f {name of this file}.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  type: LoadBalancer
```

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

This will create a load balancer that has an external ip address. You can specify one if you have a static IP as well.

Comment: Thanks I will try this I’m assuming I can use port 80

Comment: Port 80 will work just fine. This was a direct copy from the K8s docs, which has an example of ports being different for incoming and forwarding. If both are set to 80 this will work as well. Keep in mind, if you want more than one API on port 80, you'll get into needing Ingress to route requests.

Comment: the name of the file can be anything?

Comment: Yes. the command "kubectl apply -f" only uses the file name to identify the location where the yaml is kept for interpretation. Though I recommend giving your files meaningful names as a standard practice.